# How to report a Java JDK bug: choose the subcategory

Tags: java, codenameone, error-reporting

I'm in trouble on reporting the following bug, because at the page http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/start_form.jsp?checkbox1=on&submit=Start+a+new+Report I have to specify the "subcategory". I don't know what is the subcategory in this case. The bug is occurred using the Codename One Simulator, as specified here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2200

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb9a56b64d1, pid=12283, tid=0x00007fb9b7dcd700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_144-b01) (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjfxwebkit.so+0x11334d1]  checkJSPeer(long, int, OpaqueJSValue*&, OpaqueJSContext const*&)+0x41
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/francesco/NetBeansProjects/Bug/core or core.12283
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fb9c4155800):  JavaThread "JavaFX Application Thread" [_thread_in_native, id=12313, stack(0x00007fb9b7ccd000,0x00007fb9b7dce000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x00000000000002f0

Registers:
```

Comment: Since the error occurs in `libjfxwebkit.so` I'm assuming the subcategory should be "Web". However, it is not of critical importance - if it is filed under a less-than-ideal category the developers can always move it to the right one.

Comment: Ok, but in the "Subcategory" list there isn't "Web". Which available option should I select?

Comment: I can see a "Web" subcategory when selecting "JavaFX" as the main category...

Comment: That would be correct, it's a crash in the web component of JavaFX

Comment: Ok, Product/Category "JavaFX" and Subcategory "Web". I submitted the bug with all the details. sillyfly, please answer the question so I will accept your answer.